# How to split the subdirectories names?

Tags: c, posix

This code is fetching the subdirectories names that are present in a given directory. What I am trying to do is to split the subdirectories names using using a delimiter `" "` but when I print the `token` it should print the first subdirectory only but instead the code prints all the subdirectories names. I don't know what is wrong that the `strtok` is not working.

**Given result is like**

```
/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/rasta
/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd
/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd/fds
/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/fd/sub
```

**Expected result**

```
/home/bilal/Videos/folder1/rasta
```

```
char path[PATH_MAX] = "";
char path1[PATH_MAX];

void listdir(void) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    
    if (!(dir = opendir(path))) {  
        perror("opendir-path not found");
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir))) {  
        char *name = entry->d_name;   
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)    /* if "." or ".." skip */
            if (!strcmp(name, ".") || !strcmp(name, ".."))
                continue;

        snprintf(path1, 100, "%s/%s ", path, name);
        char *token = strtok(path1, " ");
        printf("%s\n", token);

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char *p;
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, name);
            listdir();           /* recursive call */
           
            if ((p = strrchr(path, '/'))) {
                if (p != path)          
                    *p = 0;  
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(path, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(path, "/home/bilal/Videos/folder1");        
    listdir();
}
```

Comment: much faster to reverse the string get the first one to marker and then reverse back.  (On modern CPUs string reverse are very fast they happen at the instruction level).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in the posted code:

- There is no need to use 2 separate path arrays, you could use `path` and remember its original length to strip the trailing part after each iteration.
- You append a space after the pathname in `snprintf(path1, 100, "%s/%s ", path, name);` and `strtok()` immediately cuts the pathname on this space: it seems redundant and even counterproductive if a component of the pathname contains a space as `strtok` will stop there instead.
- It is unclear what your goal is: each entry is printed as the function enumerates the directory entries and recurses on subdirectories.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

char path[PATH_MAX];

void listdir(void) {
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    size_t len = strlen(path);

    if (len >= sizeof(path) - 1) {
        // array too small to construct pathnames
        return;
    }
    
    if (!(dir = opendir(path)) != NULL) {  
        perror("opendir-path not found");
        return;
    }

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {  
        char *name = entry->d_name;   
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {   /* if "." or ".." skip */
            if (!strcmp(name, ".") || !strcmp(name, ".."))
                continue;
        }
        snprintf(path + len, sizeof(path) - len, "/%s", name);
        printf("%s\n", path);

        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            listdir();           /* recursive call */
        }
        path[len] = '\0';
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc > 1)
        strcpy(path, argv[1]);
    else
        strcpy(path, "/home/bilal/Videos/folder1");        
    listdir();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am working on a monitoring filesystem in which I take all the paths and monitor them. You modified the code but didn't add the split functionality in it.

Comment: Can you state your goal more precisely? why do you recurse into subdirectories if you just want to print the top one?

Comment: I took the `token` variable to make the `strtok` work. I can also go above that but that is useless if the first `token` variable is not working. As I told you that I am monitoring filesystem and using `inotify` to monitor each directory and their subdirectories also. That's why I am trying to fetch each name and give it in the `inotify instance` to monitor each path of directory and their subdirectories also. **I want to take these paths one by one and monitor them.** These paths have directories and their subdirectories. I hope you understood.

Comment: I don't understand what you intend to use `token` for. You can just pass the `path` to `inotify_add_watch()` and you can do that one by one as you enumerate the entries and recurse into subdirectories.